# androidのカメラで撮影した画像をダイアログに表示したいが上手くいかない

Tags: java, android, camera

androidのカメラで撮影した画像をダイアログに表示したいがエラー出て思った通りに行きません。
わかる方ご教授をお願いします。

エラー内容

```
パッケージ名.MainActivity$SampleClickListener$SamplePictureCallback@4288cae8
```

img_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rltWarning"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgdata"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button bt;
    SurfaceView sv;
    SurfaceHolder sh;
    Camera cm;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int Width = 10;
        int Height = 10;
        FrameLayout ll = new FrameLayout(this);
        //ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                Width, Height));
        //ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setContentView(ll);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // レイアウトに張り付け
        bt = new Button(this);
        bt.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_customize));
        bt.setText("撮影");
        bt.setWidth(10);
        bt.setHeight(10);
        sv = new SurfaceView(this);
        sh = sv.getHolder();
        sh.addCallback(new SampleSurfaceHolderCallback());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity =Gravity.CENTER+200;
        ///真ん中に設定;
        bt.setLayoutParams(params);
        ll.addView(sv);
        ll.addView(bt);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new SampleClickListener());
    }
    class SampleSurfaceHolderCallback
            implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                cm = Camera.open(0);
                Camera.Parameters pr = cm.getParameters();
                List<Size> ss = pr.getSupportedPictureSizes();
                Size s = ss.get(0);
                pr.setPictureSize(s.width, s.height);
                cm.setParameters(pr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            try {
                WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                Display dp = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
                int rt = dp.getRotation();
                int d = 0;
                switch (rt) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                        d = 90;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                        d = 0;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        d = 270;
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        d = 180;
                        break;
                }
                cm.setDisplayOrientation(d);
                cm.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());

                Camera.Parameters pr = cm.getParameters();

                List<Size> previewSizes = cm.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                Size size = previewSizes.get(0);

                pr.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                cm.setParameters(pr);
                cm.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder Holder) {
            cm.stopPreview();
            cm.release();
        }
    }
    class SampleClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bt.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                // 表示されている時に非表示に
                bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            cm.takePicture(null, null, new SamplePictureCallback());
        }
        class SamplePictureCallback implements PictureCallback {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {
                try{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "撮影完了。", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                    final View inputView = factory.inflate(R.layout.img_dialog, null);
                    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgdata);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    // ダイアログの作成(AlertDialog.Builder)
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alt = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alt.setTitle("写真")
                            .setView(inputView)
                            .setPositiveButton("保存", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("キャンセル", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }});
                    final AlertDialog dialog = alt.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("era-", toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

logcat に出力されたログ

```
03-03 14:28:01.741 184-31500/? E/QCamera3Channel: static void qcamera::QCamera3PicChannel::jpegEvtHandle(jpeg_job_status_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, mm_jpeg_output_t*, void*): Setting max jpeg size to 7558280
03-03 14:28:01.741 184-31500/? E/mm-jpeg-intf: mm_jpeg_queue_remove_job_by_job_id:2345] found matching job id
03-03 14:28:01.741 184-31500/? E/mm-still: virtual OMX_ERRORTYPE QOMXImageCodec::handleMessage():433] before wait
03-03 14:28:01.929 31152-31152/? E/era-: パッケージ名.MainActivity$SampleClickListener$SamplePictureCallback@e33580b
```

Comment: Logcatに出力されているエラーログも追記してもらってよろしいでしょうか。
http://kokufu.blogspot.jp/2012/10/exception-logcat-1.html

Answer (score 1):

※ コメントにすると改行できないのと、部分的なコード改善的な回答でもあるのでこちらに記載します。

アプリがクラッシュするエラーではなく、最後のtry〜catchでExceptionを受け取った、ということですね。
ただ

```
Log.e("era-", toString());
```

これでは `toString()` の部分は「自分自身のオブジェクトをStringに変換して出力」となってしまうので、これではException（エラー）の内容が表示できていません。

```
Log.e("era-", e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
```

として、Exceptionのメッセージを表示しつつ、スタックトレースも出力するように変えて改めてエラーメッセージを確認してみてください。

**【追記】**

`imageView1`に正しくImageView情報が取得できていないようです。

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgdata);
```

この記述では、親のMainActivityにセットしているレイアウトファイルからimgdataを探してしまうので、下の記述で取得可能になるかと思います。

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) inputView.findViewById(R.id.imgdata);
```

Comment: `E/era-: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference`
と出ました。